YAML release pipeline is getting triggered automatically by a build run completely many days before
I have a classic build pipeline and a YAML release pipeline whose YAML trigger looks something like below:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger: true

trigger: none

This means, the YAML release pipeline will automatically trigger whenever a new green build happens on the build pipeline.
Sometimes, I notice that this YAML pipeline gets automatically triggered whenever I add a tag to old build runs that were completed many days before.
Is adding a tag to an already completed build run considered a build completion event which is triggering my YAML release pipeline? How can I avoid this?


@osimans, i can reproduce the same when there's a pending tag trigger on the pipeline. You can add a new tag to update the trigger setting to avoid this appearance. I added the details below, thanks.

trigger: true basically means: "run this pipeline when any run of BuildPipelineCI completes".
You can have more control by configure the trigger filters based on branches, tags or stages. Using multiple trigger types (e.g. tags and stages) is also possible.
See Trigger one pipeline after another and Define a pipeline resource for more details.
Branch filters
You can specify the branches to include or exclude when configuring the trigger:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include: 
        - releases/*
        - main
        exclude:
        - releases/old*

Tag filters
The tags property of the trigger filters which pipeline completion events can trigger your pipeline:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger:
      tags:        # This filter is used for triggering the pipeline run
      - Production # Tags are AND'ed
      - Signed

Stage filters
You can trigger your pipeline when one or more stages of the triggering pipeline complete:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger:    
      stages:         # This stage filter is used when evaluating conditions for 
      - PreProduction # triggering your pipeline. On successful completion of all the stages
      - Production    # provided, your pipeline will be triggered.

Multiple trigger types
Consider the following resource definition:
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: SmartHotel
    project: DevOpsProject
    source: SmartHotel-CI
    trigger:
      branches:
        include:
        - releases/*
        - main
        exclude:
        - topic/*
      tags: 
      - Verified
      - Signed
      stages:
      - Production
      - PreProduction

Your pipeline will run whenever the SmartHotel-CI pipeline runs on one of the releases branches or on the main branch, is tagged with both Verified and Signed, and it completed both the Production and PreProduction stages.

Thank you so much for replying.
My concern is that the YAML release pipeline got triggered today from the build pipeline, which was completely a week ago. I just added a tag to the build run manually. So, are you saying that even though the build run was completed 7 days before, if I add a tag manually to the old build run, it will cause the YAML release pipeline to run automatically?

Also, I tried below code (TFVC repo, classic build, YAML release)
resources:
pipelines:

pipeline: tfvc-build
source: tfvc-build
trigger:
branches:
include:
- "$/mytfvcproject/my-branch"

looks like the tfvc branches are not supported under trigger branches filters?

Basically what I'm trying to say is that you can use a combination of branches/tags/stages filters to prevent undesired builds.

I tried adding a branches filter under the trigger section. My repo is TFVC-based, and it seems it's not working with TFVC branches... Can't find any MS docs that talk about TFVC branches... Are TFVC branches not supported under the trigger/branches/include block? any idea?

Are TFVC branches not supported under the trigger/branches/include block? I believe they are, but not sure if they should be configured differently. Couldn't find anything in documentation as well.


Sometimes, I notice that this YAML pipeline gets automatically triggered whenever I add a tag to old build runs that were completed many days before.
Is adding a tag to an already completed build run considered a build completion event which is triggering my YAML release pipeline? How can I avoid this?

With your pipeline resource trigger(trigger: true) in yaml, the yaml pipeline will be triggerred when the old TFVC build run is completed. If you then add tag to the old TFVC build run, it won't trigger a new yaml pipeline run. But, the yaml pipeline could be triggerred by the tag with your yaml in below scenario:

You have tag filter for pipeline resource trigger in yaml originally：

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger: 
      tags:        # This filter is used for triggering the pipeline run
      - Production # Tags are AND'ed
      - Signed

trigger: none


Run the old TFVC pipeline, it won't trigger the YAML pipeline.

Remove tags filter on pipeline resource, change to trigger: true in yaml pipeline.

resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger: true

trigger: none


Add Production and Signed tag on TFVC build run which is completed, it will trigger the yaml build by the tag.



Click into the yaml pipeline runs, it shows it's triggered by the TFVC build.

It seems like a pending trigger on the tag. To avoid such tag trigger in yaml pipeline, you can add a new tag in the filter in pipeline resource trigger to update the tag filter, if you add tags on old TFVC run(without new tag), it won't trigger the yaml pipeline.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: BuildPipelineCI
    source: BuildPipelineCI
    trigger: 
      tags:        
      - Production 
      - Signed
      - AddNew    # add new tag

